Не работает откат филамента после печати
Не рабетает откат филамента после печати, вот завершающий gcode:
G91 ;Relative positioning
G1 E-3 F2700 ;Retract a bit
G1 E-4 Z0.2 F2400 ;Retract and raise Z
G1 X5 Y5 F3000 ;Wipe out
G1 Z10 ;Raise Z more
G90 ;Absolute positioning
G1 X150 Y0 Z70 F1500

